# How to loop through a random function multiple times?

Tags: python, list, function, loops, random

```
def a4():
    p = []
    for i in range(10):
        p.append(random.sample(x, 100))
    r = []
    for i in p:
        for j in i:
            r.append(j)
    return r
```

OUTPUT:

```
[0.5202486543583558, 0.5202486543583558, 0.5202486543583558, 0.5202486543583558, 0.5202486543583558]
```

---

```
a1000 = []
for i in range(5):
    a4()
    a1000.append(statistics.mean(a4()))
print(a1000)
```

I tried to loop through the above defined function using for loop mentioned above but the function only runs once and all the loop results are basically the same. I want the function to run each time through the loop. Could someone tell me why the function is only running once?

Comment: What is `x`? If it has exactly 100 elements, then you will get the same numbers due to sampling all the elements with `random.sample`. Please, provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: yes, x has 100 elements!!

Answer (score 0):

As was pointed in the comments the sublists in `p` in the definition of `a4` have exactly the same elements, exactly the same number of times only the order of these element changes.

Therefore the same goes for every new result of `a4`. These are the same lists upto a permutation of elements. But the order of elements is irrelevant for the computation of the `mean` (the sum of permuted elements is always the same). Hence you always get the same mean as a result.

However, what you might have wanted to implement is some kind of a **bootstrapping mechanism**. In that case you would want to sample **with replacement**. And that in turn would yield different result every time. If this is what you want then replace

```
p.append(random.sample(x, 100))
```

with

```
p.append(random.choices(x, k=100))
```

Also I would consider using numpy for these things. Read about numpy array methods concatenate, flatten. And numpy.random.sample and numpy.random.choice.